# Where to install squid? on the web server or the database server?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, squid, deployment

I had my Ecommerce web application on a single server setup but now I am planning to separate out the web server and database server on different machines. Just want to understand where should I install the squid? on the web server or the database server?

Comment: Squid? I don't see a reason for squid to even be present in this design at all. What are you doing with it?!

Comment: Did you use squid (the proxy server software) as reverse proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Neither - you don't need Squid in this case. But definitely NOT on the database server. You infrastructure would be:

Users -> Squid?? -> Apache -> Database

So putting Squid on the database server would not make sense. It would also mean that your users would have some form of direct network access to your database - while not necessarily a great security issue, it is not necessary and thus shouldn't be done.

If you use squid at all, then put it on the same as your web server or on its own server.

Comment: Or on its own server.